# Express CORS sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, cors

I have an Express API hosted on ngnix that's located at `main-domain.tld/api/` and an admin panel located at `sub.main-domain.tld` that sends requests to my API.

When I try to send requests from my admin panel to my API I get a CORS error the 70% of the times doesn't matter which route I'm requesting and which method I use (POST, GET etc.).

**I can't understand 2 things:**

- The first is why I'm receiving a CORS error since I enabled all
  origins from my API source code.
- The second is why am I receiving a CORS error only the 70% of the
  times my admin panel makes a request, that shouldn't happen if my API was set up the wrong way, right ?

I searched for a solution all day and tried to create `corsOptions` in every way possible but I still got the same problem, doesn't matter what I do.

**CORS Error:**

[image: CORS Error (Chrome Console)]

**API source code:**

```js
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import { generateToken, getCleanUser } from './utils';

import { Admins, Utenti, Prodotti, Acquisti } from './models';

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://domain', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
}).then(db => console.log('Il DB è connesso!'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// CORS
app.use(cors());
// parse application/json
app.use(express.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Middleware that checks if JWT token exists and verifies it if it does exist.
// In all future routes, this helps to know if the request is authenticated or not.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  let token = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (!token) return next(); //if no token, continue

  token = token.replace('Bearer ', '');
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Invalid user."
      });
    } else {
      req.user = user; //set the user to req so other routes can use it
      next();
    }
  });
});

// request handlers
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid user to access it.' });
  res.send('Welcome! - ' + req.user.username);
});


//*================================
//* ADMINS SIGNIN
//*================================
app.post('/api/admins/signin', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.body.username;
    const pwd = req.body.password;

    // return 400 status if username/password is not exist
    if (!user || !pwd) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Username or Password required!"
      });
    }

    await Admins.findOne({ 'username': user, 'password': pwd }, (err, data) => {

      if (err) {
        console.error('DB ERROR  =>  ', err);
      }

      // return 401 status if the credential is not match.
      if (!data) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: true,
          message: "Username or Password is Wrong!"
        });
      }

      // generate token
      const token = generateToken(data);
      // get basic user details
      const userObj = getCleanUser(data);
      // return the token along with user details
      return res.json({ user: userObj, token });

    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DI ADMIN SIGNIN >> ${error}`);
    return res.status(400);
  }
});

//*================================
//* USERS SIGNIN
//*================================
app.post('/api/users/signin', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.body.username;
    const pwd = req.body.password;

    // return 400 status if username/password is not exist
    if (!user || !pwd) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Username or Password required!"
      });
    }

    await Utenti.findOne({ 'username': user, 'password': pwd }, (err, data) => {

      if (err) {
        console.error('DB ERROR  =>  ', err);
      }

      // return 401 status if the credential is not match.
      if (!data) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: true,
          message: "Username or Password is Wrong!"
        });
      }

      // generate token
      const token = generateToken(data);
      // get basic user details
      const userObj = getCleanUser(data);
      // return the token along with user details
      return res.json({ user: userObj, token });

    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DI USERS SIGNIN >> ${error}`);
    return res.status(400);
  }
});

//*================================
//* USERS SIGNUP
//*================================
app.post('/api/users/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // return 400 status if username/password is not exist
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Every field in the form is required!"
      });
    }

    await Utenti.findOne({ 'username': req.body.username }, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('DB ERROR  =>  ', err);
      }

      if (data) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: true,
          message: "Username already taken!"
        });
      }

      await Utenti.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).exec(async (err, lastUserSignedUp) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'DB Problem... '
        });

        let newUser;

        if (lastUserSignedUp[0]) {
          newUser = new Utenti({
            id: (lastUserSignedUp[0].id + 1),
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email
          });
        } else {
          newUser = new Utenti({
            id: 0,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email
          });
        }

        await newUser.save();
        return res.json(newUser);
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DI USERS SIGNUP >> ${error}`);
    return res.status(401)
  }
});

//*================================
//* ADMINS VERIFY THE TOKEN
//*================================
app.get('/api/verifyAdminToken', (req, res) => {
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: true,
      message: "Token is required."
    });
  }

  // check token that was passed by decoding token using secret
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, user) => {
    try {
      if (err) return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Invalid token."
      });

      await Admins.findOne({ 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password }, (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
          console.error('DB ERROR  =>  ', err);
        }

        // return 401 status if the userId does not match.
        if (user._id !== data._id.toString()) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            error: true,
            message: "Invalid user."
          });
        }
        // get basic user details
        const userObj = getCleanUser(data);
        return res.json({ user: userObj, token });

      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERRORE NELLA GET REQUEST DI VERIFY-TOKEN >> ${error}`);
    }
  });
});

//*================================
//* USERS VERIFY THE TOKEN
//*================================
app.get('/api/verifyToken', (req, res) => {
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: true,
      message: "Token is required."
    });
  }

  // check token that was passed by decoding token using secret
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, user) => {
    try {
      if (err) return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Invalid token."
      });

      await Utenti.findOne({ 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password }, (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
          console.error('DB ERROR  =>  ', err);
        }

        // return 401 status if the userId does not match.
        if (user._id !== data._id.toString()) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            error: true,
            message: "Invalid user."
          });
        }
        // get basic user details
        const userObj = getCleanUser(data);
        return res.json({ user: userObj, token });

      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERRORE NELLA GET REQUEST DI VERIFY-TOKEN >> ${error}`);
    }
  });
});

//*================================
//* PRODOTTI
//*================================
app.route('/api/prodotti')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (req.query.categoria !== undefined) {
        if (req.query.categoria === 'all') {
          await Prodotti.find().exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            return res.json(data);
          })
        } else {
          await Prodotti.find({ 'categoria': req.query.categoria }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            return res.json(data);
          })
        }
      } else {
        if (!req.query.id) {
          await Prodotti.findOne({ 'nome': req.query.nome }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            if (req.query.desc === 'true' && data) {
              return res.json(data.desc);
            } else {
              return res.json(data);
            }
          });
        } else {
          await Prodotti.findOne({ 'id': req.query.id }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            return res.json(data);
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERRORE NELLA GET REQUEST DEI PRODOTTI >> ${error}`);
    }
  })
  .post(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
      try {
        await Admins.findOne({ 'username': req.user.username, 'password': req.user.password }, async (err, data) => {

          if (err) {
            console.error('DB ERROR  =>  ', err);
          }

          // return 401 status if the credential is not match.
          if (!data) {
            return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: "Access Denied"
            });
          }

          await Prodotti.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).exec(async (err, lastProdottoAggiunto) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            let nuovoProdotto;

            if (lastProdottoAggiunto[0]) {
              nuovoProdotto = new Prodotti({
                id: (lastProdottoAggiunto[0].id + 1),
                nome: req.body.nome,
                categoria: req.body.categoria,
                prezzo: req.body.prezzo,
                id_api: req.body.id_api,
                desc: req.body.desc
              });
            } else {
              nuovoProdotto = new Prodotti({
                id: 0,
                nome: req.body.nome,
                categoria: req.body.categoria,
                prezzo: req.body.prezzo,
                id_api: req.body.id_api,
                desc: req.body.desc
              });
            }

            await nuovoProdotto.save();
            return res.json(nuovoProdotto);
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DEI PRODOTTI >> ${error}`);
      }
      return res.status(403).json({
        error: true,
        message: 'Access Denied'
      });
    }
  })
  .delete(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Prodotti.findOneAndDelete({ 'id': req.body.id }, (err, removed) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'DB Problem... '
        });
        return res.json({ success: 'true' });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DEI PRODOTTI >> ${error}`);
    }
  });

//*================================
//* ACQUISTI
//*================================
app.route('/api/acquisti')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (!req.query.id) {
        await Acquisti.find({ 'id': req.query.id }, (err, data) => {
          if (err) return res.status(401).json({
            error: true,
            message: 'DB Problem... '
          });

          return res.json(data);
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERRORE NELLA GET REQUEST DEGLI ACQUISTI >> ${error}`);
    }
  })
  .post(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
      try {
        const nuovoAcquisto = new Acquisti({
          id: orderId,
          id: req.body.id,
          categoria: req.body.categoria,
          nome: req.body.nome,
          link: req.body.link,
          qty: req.body.qty,
          spesa: req.body.spesa
        });
        await nuovoAcquisto.save();
        return res.json(nuovoAcquisto);

      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: true,
          message: `ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DEGLI ACQUISTI >> ${error}`
        });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(403).json({
        error: true,
        message: 'Access Denied'
      });
    }
  });

//*================================
//* UTENTI
//*================================
app.route('/api/utenti')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
      try {
        if (req.query.id) {
          await Utenti.findOne({ 'id': req.query.id }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            return res.json(data);
          });
        } else {
          await Utenti.find().exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(401).json({
              error: true,
              message: 'DB Problem... '
            });

            return res.json(data);
          })
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`ERRORE NELLA GET REQUEST DEGLI UTENTI >> ${error}`);
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(403).send(`
      <div style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;">
      </div>
      `);
    }
  })
  .delete(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Utenti.findOneAndDelete({ 'id': req.body.id }, (err, removed) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'DB Problem... '
        });
        return res.json({ success: 'true' });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERRORE NELLA POST REQUEST DEI PRODOTTI >> ${error}`);
    }
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Porta API: ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, this structure is wrong `await Admins.findOne({ 'username': user, 'password': pwd }, (err, data) => { ...});`  You don't use `await` AND pass a callback to your database.  Pick one or the other.  If you pass a callback, then the request does NOT return a promise and thus the `await` is pointless (does nothing).  If you don't pass a callback, then it will return a promise and you can actually get the result from the `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my `nginx` configuration and **Cloudflare** that was blocking the CORs headers.

This is the new working nginx configuration:

```bash
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        
        root /var/www/main-domain.tld;
        index index.html;

        server_name main-domain.tld www.main-domain.tld;
        
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
                root /var/www/main-domain.tld;
                internal;
        }

        error_page 400 401 403 503 /custom_50x.html;
        location = /custom_50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
        location / {
          if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
          }
          if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
          }
          if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
          }
        
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
          if ($request_filename ~* ^.+.html$) {
            break;
          }
          # add .html to URI and serve file, directory, or symlink if it exists
          if (-e $request_filename.html) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.html last;
            break;
          }
          if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
          }
        }
        location /api {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:api-port;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

And here is how to fix **Cloudflare**. Follow the instructions for "Adding or changing CORS headers" and send the correct CORs headers at least once:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200308847-Using-cross-origin-resource-sharing-CORS-with-Cloudflare

Answer (score 2):

You are making a cross origin request that triggers pre-flight (this can be seen from what is logged in the browser).  This is an additional level of CORs that can be caused by any number of things such as custom headers, content-type beyond a small permitted set, etc...  Apparently only some of your requests are triggering pre-flight which is why some of them work fine and others do not.  You can read about [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) and [pre-flighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) requests and see what causes the browser to decide it has to pre-flight a request.

If you look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger, you will be able to see the browser make the OPTIONS request and probably get back a 404 or not get the right headers back which is the reason the pre-flight request fails and the browser then denies the CORs request.

To allow a pre-flighted CORs request, your server has to response to the OPTIONS request with a 2xx status and proper CORS headers.

You will need an `app.options(...)` request handler that either allows all requests through or allows only certain requests through by returning the proper CORS headers and responding with a 2xx status (commonly 204).

Since you're using the `cors` module to help you, you can read about pre-flight requests with that module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: I added `app.options('*', cors());` to my code but the problem persists. In the Network tab of Chrome I see 2 requests were made: 1° [link](https://i.imgur.com/N4VEpqO.png) and 2° [link](https://i.imgur.com/AtSjkZs.jpg). The error in the Chrome Console is still the exact same one.

Comment: @SteveStifler - Did you place that `app.options('*', cors());` BEFORE all your routes?  I see that the OPTIONS request is getting a 200 status code, but it isn't getting the CORS headers on it.  What does the browser console show now when this request fails?

Comment: I put the `app.options('*', cors());` under the `app.use(cors());`. This is the error in the console: [link](https://i.imgur.com/kgYW5Ho.jpg).

Comment: @SteveStifler - Something is not righ about the request ordering because you're not getting the `Access-Control` type headers on your response to the OPTIONS request.  Your screenshot of the response headers does not show any of them being present.  The OPTIONS response needs to both be a 2xx status and have the right CORs response headers on it.  You are missing the headers.  I can't really do more without seeing the current state of the file.

Comment: @SteveStifler - You can show the current state of your file to me either in an external link to the whole source code file or add it to the end of your question (do NOT replace what you already have in the question - that should stay there), but you can use the "edit" link to add a new revision to the end of your question.

Comment: This is a link to my source code files: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F4MVU1-9MSnQAMquW8T0I6IhizgpVYvT?usp=sharing). Sorry for being a bit late but I had to eat something.

Comment: @SteveStifler - I'm going to have to run some tests here, not sure why that isn't working.

Comment: @SteveStifler - I cannot reproduce your problem.  The suggested code should work.  When I attempt to reproduce your problem in a very simple server, a pre-flighted cross origin request works fine.  But, you can see from your screen shot [here](https://i.imgur.com/AtSjkZs.jpg) that there are no CORs headers on the pre-flighted response which is clearly a problem.  Is there any chance there is a proxy or something like that in the way that is not forwarding these headers?

Comment: I use nginx as a reverse proxy, so maybe that's the problem. But I don't know how to set it up so it wouldn't block CORs headers. Here is my `/api/` config file: [link](https://i.imgur.com/VyKjqnu.png). Here is my `adminpanel.domain.tld` config file: [link](https://i.imgur.com/FJGizhE.png). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SteveStifler - Sorry, but I don't know nginx to be able to comment on that configuration.  Perhaps you could do the right logging on your Express server to see exactly what headers are coming out of the server and compare that to what's in the client to see for sure if it is nginx removing them or not.

Comment: I finally found and fixed the problem. The problem was my nginx configuration and Cloudflare that was blocking my headers. Thank you anyways for your help.

Comment: @SteveStifler - Well, that was my last guess.  Glad you figured it out.